# Using TextView to inflate Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Upon clicking each TextView they should lead to another layout file to help the user learn about human trafficking. In the onCreate method I have setOnClickListener to my text view. Inflating it is an issue though. Is this called inflating a view? I've seen people recommending the use of fragments for this, using setContentView (from what I've found this shouldn't be used), and using the layout inflater while passing in the layout I want and null. However that doesn't work. How should this code look?

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.piatt.worksafe.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Work Safe!"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What is Human Trafficing?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/whatIsHumanTrafficing"
    android:clickable="true"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How do I get safe labor?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/whatIsHumanTrafficing"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/howDoIGetSafeLabor"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How do I check that my job / job offer is legal?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/howDoIGetSafeLabor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/checkLegality"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How can I get help?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkLegality"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/getHelp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About us"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getHelp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/aboutUs"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView whatIsHumanTrafficing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.whatIsHumanTrafficing);
    whatIsHumanTrafficing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View view){

           //What is this context, why do I need it and where does it come from? 
           //What is the ViewGroup, why do I need it and where does it come from?
           view.inflate(Context context, R.layout.what_is_human_trafficing, ViewGroup root);
       }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Aside: You could read the documentation for [`View.inflate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup))</sup>

> What is this context, why do I need it and where does it come from?

What: `YourActivity.this` (replace with your actual class name)

Why: You need it as a parameter to inflate a View.

> What is the ViewGroup, why do I need it and where does it come from?

You probably don't need it; it can be null. It is the ViewGroup to inflate the View into. Like for a ListView, you would load each row into the list as the "group".

---

Anyways, if you want to dynamically show different layout file based upon what is clicked, yes `Fragment`'s are one way to do that, and so are `ViewStub`'s.

And you aren't actually calling `inflate` on the TextView because it is a static method. It is equivalent to doing this with a `LayoutInflater`

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
// TODO: Do something with v
```

Comment: When I inflate(R.layout.your_layout) it wants another parameter. It tells me @Nullable Viewgroup root. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Same answer as before. It can be `null` (as you see by the `@Nullable` argument)

Comment: Null isn't posing a problem now. I got a reference to the relative layout `rl` and added the view `rl.addView(v);`. When I run the app it displays the text over the previous layout. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably either 1) Should add layout parameters to say "this view is below this other view" or 2) Use a LinearLayout instead.

Comment: I think I misrepresented my intention. When the text view is pressed I want the main layout I'm on to disappear and the new one to appear. Not appear under the layout. What vocabulary can I use to express this better?

Comment: Oh. Then why can't you just replace the text of the textview? Or rather than having the TextView capture the click, have some layout that contains the TextView that you could remove the TextView and add the layout that you want?

Comment: My intention is that each view is made up of multiple text views explaining what human trafficking is and other things. Clicking on one allows another layout with more text views to appear. Should I attempt this with intents?

Comment: You could start new Activities to make it simple. I don't really know how your app is laid out, though. I think my post has answered your initial question though about inflating the view. If you would like to provide a more in-depth question about your app, you may post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The final code should look like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splashScreenId);
    TextView whatIsHumanTrafficing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.whatIsHumanTrafficing);
    whatIsHumanTrafficing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View view){


           MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.what_is_human_trafficing);

       }
    });

}
```

Set an on click listener to the text view then within it on `MainActivity.this` set the content view to the layout you want.

Comment: I would advise against this. `setContentView` (as the name implies) overwrites the content view, therefore `findViewById` will stop working reliably. Therefore, getting back to the previous content view is a challenge. If you want to do it this way, then swapping Fragments are recommended.

Comment: I just ran into this when I tried to press the back button. I'll implement it with fragments tomorrow. Thanks for the advice, this has been a learning experience.